# Images in JSON AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to AngularJS, so sometimes when I do some mistake that is obvious, I still can't figure out what is going wrong with my code. So saying, here is my doubt:

HTML code:

```
<body ng-controller = "Ctrl">
<script id="Page6.html" type="text/ng-template">
<div class="list card" style="background-color: beige">

  <div class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter display name" ng-model="user.nam">
  </div>

<a ng-click = "saveedit(user)"<button class="button button-clear">SAVE DETAILS</button></a>
</div>
</script>
</body>
```

CONTROLLER.JS

```
.controller('Ctrl',function($scope,$rootScope,ContactService){
$rootScope.saveedit=function(user) {    

        ContactService.save({names: user.nam, image:"images.jpg"},ContactService.getid("Donkey"));

    }
});
```

THIS IS THE SERVICE:

```
.service('ContactService', function () {
var items = [
        { id: 1, names: 'Dolphin',  image: 'dolphin.jpg',}, { id: 2, names: 'Donkey',  image: 'donkey.jpg'}, { id: 3,  empid: 'FG2043', image: 'penguin.jpg'}];

var im = [{image: ''}];
var ctr=0;
var uid=3;

this.save = function (contact,id) {
       ctr=0;
       for (i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
       if(items[i].id == id)
       {
       im[0].image= items[i].image;
       ctr=100;
       break;
       }
       }


            uid = (uid+1);
            contact.id = uid;

            items.push(contact);
            if (ctr==100 ) {
            alert("in save putting the image");

            items[contact.id].image = im[0].image; //doubt

            alert("finished putting image");
        }      
    }

    //simply search items list for given id
    //and returns the object if found

    this.getid = function (name) {

        for (i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
            if (items[i].names == name) {
                return (i+1);
            }
        }           

    }

    //simply returns the items list
    this.list = function () {
        return items;
    }
});
```

The problem I am facing is this: Everything works, except one thing. In ContactService, push() function, the line I have commented as //doubt is not getting executed.

The alert before it "in save putting the image" runs, but the alert "finished putting image" doesn't. What is the mistake there??

Comment: Did you open console? There is an error which tells you what mistake is.

Comment: are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: nope, no errors in console, but no worries, as Amine pointed out, it was an index problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using the `id`'s, which start at 1, to navigate in an array whose indexes start at 0.

To access the most recently pushed element, you should rather do :

```
items[contact.id - 1].image = im[0].image;
```

But you actually don't need to access the array : `items[contact.id - 1]` will return the object that you just pushed, and which is already referenced by variable `contact`, so you could just do :

```
contact.image = im[0].image;
```